# How to apply adjustment layer to layer mask?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, mask

Everything on Google is how to apply masks to adjustment layers and I wan't the opposite. I have a mask and want to apply a levels adjustment to it. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, but the mask wont stay affected by the adjustment layer.

Comment: I think you might be thinking this the wrong way. I mean.. technically you could do it, but it would be way too convoluted and wouldn't make much sense. You can however use `Image > Adjustments > ..` on a mask.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is used generally to alter the tonal structure of a layer mask. Do the following:

1. Target the layer mask (click on it), you should see the frame to move from the layer icon to the layer mask icon. To make sure, click on the layer icon and the layer mask icon to see the switch.
2. If you want to see only the layer mask, Alt-Click on the layer mask icon which will show just the mask
3. Press Ctrl-L which will bring the Levels adjustment
4. Adjust the levels and see the result.

I trust this is what you are trying to achieve, let us know how you make out.